# Spring MVC Java why are extra request params being added to my url?

Tags: java, spring, forms, jsp, model-view-controller

I have a website, called `website.com`. I have a form which looks like this:

```
<form:form method="get" id="profileForm" modelAttribute="profile" onsubmit="updateFormAction()">
                    <form:label path="username">Name</form:label>
                    <form:input path="username" id="usernameInput"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                </form:form>

                <script>
                    function updateFormAction() {
                        var username = document.getElementById("usernameInput").value;
                        var form = document.getElementById("profileForm");
                        form.action = "/profile/" + username;
                    }
                </script>
```

What the form url should look like is this: `website.com/profile/username123`

However, it is processing it as `website.com/profile/username123?username=username123`

This is my web controller mapping method:

```
@GetMapping ("/profile/{username}")
    public String profile(@PathVariable("username") String name, Model model, RestTemplate restTemplate) throws JsonProcessingException {
```

When I set `<form method="post"` it works. However, I do not want this behaviour, as I can only post that url through that form. I want to be able to search it via a link instead.

I have tried `@ModelAttribute("username") String username`, however the url looks like `website.com/profile/?username=username123`

Any ideas how I can fix this? Should I not be using a form, but a `button onsubmit` parameter instead?

Comment: You should send the request through JS not modify the form action. Because the GET will always add the parameters to the URL. So instead of rewriting the URL in the form you should be using `fetch` to send the request (and return `false` from your JS function to prevent the default from happening).

Answer (score 0):

Why are you adding `username` in `path variable` ?
I think you can remove `onSubmit` attribute and for `action` add `/profile` and make your http verb to post in `form` and `controller` .
You can create an object called `profile` that has a field called `username`;
In your `controller` in inputs add

```
@ModelAttribute("profile") Profile profile;
```

then you can get `username` in `profile` sth like this :

```
@PostMapping ("/profile")
public String profile(@ModelAttribute("profile") Profile profile) {
```

Comment: I have tried this already, however with POST requests I can only access a resource from the form itself, not from a link.

Comment: With a post it doesn't matter if it is a request parameter or a form parameter it will bind either way.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't pass any parameter in the url then you should not submit the form. Just return `false` from the onsubmit function. This will prevent form submission or use a button `type="button"` with onclick event handler. Then use redirect directly to the url specified.

```
<script>
  function updateFormAction() {
     var username = document.getElementById("usernameInput").value;
     window.location.href = "/profile/" + username;
     return false;
  }
</script>
```